# Парсинг JSON с разными именами node

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

JSON:

```
"mainObject": {
    "name1": {
        "giud": null,
        "param_name": "param_value"
        "param_name": "param_value"
        "param_name": "param_value"
    },
    "name2": {
        "giud": null,
        "param_name": "param_value"
        "param_name": "param_value"
        "param_name": "param_value"
    },
    "name3": {
        "giud": null,
        "param_name": "param_value"
        "param_name": "param_value"
        "param_name": "param_value"
    },      
}
```

Я хочу сериализировать этот Json в объект, и рисую архитектуру класса (последний на данный момент вариант):

```
namespace PdfFillerIntegration.Models.ReverseMapping
{
    public class MappingRelationCollector
    {
        public List<RelatedNode> mainObject { get; set; }

    }

    public class RelatedNode
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> node { get; set; }
    }
```

При этом name1...nameN - всегда разные значения

Вылетаю на строке `name1": {` я получаю ошибку:

> 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PdfFillerIntegration.Models.ReverseMapping.RelatedNode]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'mainObject.name1'

**Подскажите пожалуйста, какая в данном случае должна быть архитектура класса?**

Спасибо

P.S.
Кроме варианта `JObject.Parse(inputJson)`

Comment: Вы что-то делаете изначально не так! Напишите подробнее почему у вас динамический набор параметров?

Comment: Мне приходит  JSON в таком формате, на его структуру я повлиять не могу. По факту там может быть произвольное количество нод "NameN".

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился следующим образом:

```
[JsonProperty("mainObject")]
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> MainObject { get; set; }
```